# A question on the Laplace Transform of $f(t)=t e^{at}\sin (bt)$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, laplace-transform, closed-form

I would like to solve the Laplace transform of the following function:

> $$t \mapsto t e^{at}\sin (bt).$$

I know that $\mathscr{L}\left(\sin(bt)\right)=\dfrac{b}{s^2+b^2}$ and that you have to take the integral from $0$ to $\infty$ and multiply it by $e^{-st}$.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Just looking to get some help with this calculation and integral

Comment: start with using Latex, and not writing $\sin bt = \frac{b}{s^2+b^2}$ !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. From standard properties (see this [table](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf)) and from the given result one gets
$$
\mathscr{L}\left(t \sin bt \right)(s)=-\left(\mathscr{L}\left( \sin bt \right)\right)'(s)=\frac{2bs}{(s^2+b^2)^2}
$$ then using
$$
\mathscr{L}\left(e^{at}f(t) \right)(s)=\left(\mathscr{L}f\right)(s-a) 
$$ gives finally

> $$
> \mathscr{L}\left(t e^{at}\sin (bt) \right)(s)=\frac{2b(s-a)}{((s-a)^2+b^2)^2}.
> $$

Comment: Okay so then I just need to evauluate from 0 to infinity?

Comment: @javahelper123 It's already done.

Comment: Isn't e^(at) = 1/(s-a)

Comment: @javahelper123 Yes. But here we have $e^{at}\cdot f(t)$, not only $e^{at}$.

Comment: And why do you put the s on the end in brackets like that?

Comment: Because the variable in the initial function is $t$, whereas the variable in the Laplace transform is $s$.

Comment: Okay and where you say e^(at)•f(t)  is f(t) e^(-st)

Comment: It's rather $\mathscr{L}\left(e^{at}\cdot f(t) \right)(s)=\left(\mathscr{L}f\right)(s-a)$. Thus if you know the L transform of $f$, you just deduce the L transform of $e^{at} \cdot f$ this way.

Comment: Okay so this should be good enough as a solution to this question?

Comment: I think it's fine as a solution. Thank you.

Comment: Okay awesome thanks for your time

Comment: @javahelper123 of course if you think that $\sin b t = \frac{b^2}{b^2+s^2}$ (in latex : $\text{\$\sin b t = \frac{b^2}{b^2+s^2}\$}$) you won't go very far

Comment: @user1952009 You are right, but I think the OP means the 'Laplace transform of...', that's why I've edited his question accordingly.

Comment: yes saw that, what worries me is that he didn't edit, and wrote again 'Isn't e^(at) = 1/(s-a) ' (@javahelper123)